# border style change when set background

Tags: asp.net, css, background, textbox

I create textbox in asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="ajaxCalendar" ID="tDate"></asp:TextBox>
```

I set the background to image in css file

```
.ajaxCalendar
    {
        background-image:url(../Images/SCalendar.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position-y:center; 
    }
```

What happens is that if I change a setting of the background also border style changes

the text box with the above code:
[image]

the text box without setting a background:(empty style)
[image]

**Please note the difference in border**

Comment: Try explicitly setting `border: 1px solid #000` as well.

Comment: Where is your border style coming from? The one you expect is not the default border of a textbox.

Comment: this is the default border;

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border explicitly in for your CSS class will solve the problem.

```
.ajaxCalendar
{
    background-image:url(../Images/SCalendar.png);  
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position-y:center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: this not work, this make the textbox size different of all textbox